# How can i combine two columns containing Richtext data/files

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to maniupulate richtext / *.rtf data in SQL server 2005 / 2008
I have looked at ocx solutions. Maybe creating some CLR stored procs??

The problem is that I have several notes written in richtext that need to be combined for ease of reporting.
Like
SELECT @Notes = @Notes + RTFColumn FROM Notestable WHERE ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLR would be the equivalent of writing a program and might not work as efficiently.

The database isn't really designed to do what you are asking of it and, a CLR sproc that handled it would be blocking, on many levels. So you would be better off writing a program that manually processed through the rows to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably better off creating a simple application to read the two files, merge the data and save if that is where you are heading.  Its sounds like you are expecting the database to do something outside of its store/retrieve job functions...